# Matching multiple objects using IValueProvider.GetValue

Tags: c#, string

I have following piece of code:

```
var ids = bindingContext
            .ValueProvider
            .GetValue("Factors.Item1")
            .AttemptedValue;
```

the get value's argument might be either `"Factors.Item1"` or `"Factors.Item_Check"`. I wonder if there's a way for checking both cases in one line, for example something like this:

```
var ids = bindingContext
            .ValueProvider
            .GetValue("Factors.Item1" | "Factors.Item_Check")
            .AttemptedValue;
```

Comment: Can you elaboration more, what you wanna do?

Comment: did u mean one variable might have value either 1 of these 2? and only then execute the code to get value?

Comment: @DeepakSharma One or all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is not. The interface doesn't contain a method to retrieve multiple values, and a binary OR isn't going to help either.

The best I could come up with is this:

```
var ids = new[] { "Factors.Item1", "Factors.Item_Check"}
            .Select( v => bindingContext
                          .ValueProvider
                          .GetValue(v)
                          .AttemptedValue
                  )
            .ToArray(); // materialize if you need to
```

Comment: Or possibly `.FirstOrDefault()`, depending on what "OR" means for OP.

Comment: Yup. Forgot to mention that @Groo.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Great, thanks, Is it possible to have `"Factors.Item_Check"` as a pattern, for example `"Factors.Item_Check\d"` inside the array?

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: @PatrickHofman It throws an exception when only one key exists inside `ValueProvider
`: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`